# Factorising $D^{2n} - I$ and $D^n - I$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\rm(ii)$ Let $\mathcal P_{11}(\Bbb R)$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leqslant11$ over the field $\Bbb R$ and let $D:\mathcal P_{11}(\Bbb R)\to\mathcal P_{11}(\Bbb R)$ be the linear map given by differentiation. Write down the least positive integer $n$ for which $D^{2n}=0$ on $\mathcal P_{11}(\Bbb R)$. 
 By factorisation of the formal expressions $D^{2n}-I$, $D^n-1$ or otherwise, show that the mapping $$D^9-D^6+D^3-I:\mathcal P_{11}(\Bbb R)\to\mathcal P_{11}(\Bbb R)$$

I can't seem to get a factor of $D^9-D^6 + D^3 - I$,could someone show me how to get the factor they require? I'm assuming it's in the form of $D^{12}-I$, but all I have is $D^{12} - I = (D^4-I)(D^8+D^4+I)$ by guess work

Comment: This is similar to what you have, but you want to go in multiples of 3, and switch the sign. You're close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Use polynomial division.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$D^{12}=0=(D^3+I)(D^9-D^6+D^3-I)+I$$
so $D^9-D^6+D^3-I$ is invertible and it's inverse is $-(D^3+I)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,x = D^3.$ Then $\,\overbrace{\color{#0a0}{x^4}\!\color{#c00}{-\!1}}^{\large D^{12}-1} = (\color{#0a0}{ax}\!+\!\color{#c00}b) (\overbrace{\color{#0a0}{x^3}\! -\! x^2\! +\! x\! \color{#c00}{-\! 1}}^{\large D^9-D^6+D^3-1})\,\Rightarrow \,\color{#0a0}a=1 =\color{#c00} b\,$ by comparing $\rm\color{#0a0}{lead}/\color{#c00}{trail}$ coefs

Answer (score 0):

If $E = D^3$, your polynomial is $P = E^3 - E^2 + E - I$. What is $P \cdot (E + I)$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
D^9-D^6 + D^3 - I & = D^6(D^3 - I) + (D^3 - I)
\\ &= (D^6 + I)(D^3 - I)
\\ &= (D^6 + I)(D - I)(D^2 + D + I)
\\ &= (D^2 + I)(D^4 - D^2 + I)(D - I)(D^2 + D + I)
\end{align}$$